# Charts with DevExpress / DevExtreme

Tags: charts, devexpress, devextreme

Hi I'm searching for a good chart plugin for my web-application, which can solve some of my requirements. To date, I've tested follow chart plugins:

- Kendo UI
- FusionCharts
- HighCharts
- Angular Charts

The plugin highcharts solves all of my requirements, but it's really expensive. The others don't solve all of my requirements, so I have to search another one. The solution of a hand-made chart needs a lot of time and that means for our company, it's also expensive. Now I've found the framework **DevExpress**. Before I invest a lot of time to test it, I would like to inform myself, if it's possible to make charts with DevExpress with this requirements:

- Any number of y-axes with various values
- Events (detect if clicked for example)
- Costume style with css (I think I saw it on their website)
- Integrate it as HTML in custome code
- Supports JSON
- Mixed line-style (for example, a part of a line in the chart is solid, another is dotted, but it's the same line)
- Responsive Design

**My results with highcharts:**

Any number of y-axes with various value types:
[image]

Mixed linetypes in same line (blue line):
[image]

Special chart constalations:
[image]

This special requirements are for the healthcare, because they have some weird and special charts they need for checking medical results. So it's simply complicate, to find a good plugin. If there is someone who has a knowledge with DevExpress and charts and can answer me I would be thankfull.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any number of y-axes with various values

DevExtreme has [Multiple Axes Demo](http://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/#demo/charts-advanced_features-multiple_axes)

> Events (detect if clicked for example)

DevExtreme Charts have [handlers](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Visualization_Widgets/dxChart/Configuration/?version=16_1#onPointClick) for [events](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Visualization_Widgets/dxChart/Events/?version=16_1). Here is a [demo illustrates onPointClick](http://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/#demo/charts-advanced_features-api_-_select_a_point)

> Costume style with css (I think I saw it on their website)

See it in [Appearance Customization Article](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Data_Visualization/Common/Appearance_Customization/?version=16_1#Palettes) & [Customize Points and Labels demo](http://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/#demo/charts-advanced_features-customize_points_and_labels)

> Supports JSON

[Remote Data Source Using an Ajax Query](http://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/#demo/charts-remote_data_source-using_an_ajax_query) Demo

> Responsive Design

DevExtreme Charts looks good on phones, tablets and desktops ([Mobile](http://js.devexpress.com/MobileDevelopment/DataVisualization/) & [Web](http://js.devexpress.com/WebDevelopment/Charts/))

You can see more in [Widgets Gallery Demo](http://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/) & [Documentation](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Visualization_Widgets/?version=16_1)

Comment: Hi and thanks for you're answer! I'm working right now on an example to make a chart with all my requirements on it. I will post it here, so everybody can se how to do this. Cheers!

Comment: Hi please check my current results with devextreme charts and my problems/questions in connection with my requirements:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990461/mixed-line-style-of-same-line-in-devextreme-chart

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38007034/costumize-tooltip-in-dxchart