# Mixed line-style of same line in DevExtreme chart

Tags: javascript, charts, devexpress, devextreme

Hi I'm working for the first time with the charts of the DevExtreme Framework, because I'm searching for a good chart plugin for my web-application, which can solve some of my special requirements. At the moment my chart looks like this (I can't put it in a fiddle or in the stackoverflow snippet, because there I got an error, when a put an external library for globalize/chartjs.js so I copied into the question):

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>DevExtreme Chart</title>
        <!--FRAMEWOKR-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./lib/globalize.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./lib/dx.charts.js"></script>
        <!--JS-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="chart.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chartContainer" style="width:100%; height: 600px"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dataSource = [
        {
            argument: '15.06.2016',
            puls: 102,
            temperatur: 37.6,
            weight: 89
        },
        {
            argument: '16.06.2016',
            puls: 99,
            temperatur: 35.1,
            weight: 88
        },
        {
            argument: '17.06.2016',
            puls: 87,
            temperatur: 38.0,
            weight: 87
        },
        {
            argument: '18.06.2016',
            puls: 91,
            temperatur: 36.3,
            weight: 88
        },
        {
            argument: '19.06.2016',
            puls: 112,
            temperatur: 37.1,
            weight: 90
        }
    ];

    $("#chartContainer").dxChart({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        commonSeriesSettings: {
            type: "spline",
            label: {
                visible: false,
                connector: {
                    visible: false
                }
            },
            argumentField: "argument",
            axis: "pulsAxe"
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: true
        },
        series: [
            {
                name: "Puls",
                valueField: "puls",
            },
            {
                name: "Temperatur",
                valueField: "temperatur",
                axis: "temperaturAxe"
            },
            {
                name: "Gewicht",
                valueField: "weight",
                axis: "weightAxe"
            }
        ],
        valueAxis: [
            {
                name: "pulsAxe",
                title: "Puls",
                label: {
                    customizeText: function(value) {
                        return value.value + " bpm"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                name: "temperaturAxe",
                title: "Temperatur",
                position: "right",
                label: {
                    customizeText: function(value) {
                        return value.value + " °C"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                name: "weightAxe",
                title: "Gewicht",
                position: "right",
                label: {
                    customizeText: function(value) {
                        return value.value + " kg"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

**My result:**
[image]

Now I would like to change the red line like the blue line in this example (this chart is **not** devextreme, it's highcharts):

[image]

My goal is, also to mix line-style in the same line on a specific zone (I would like to say, this part is solid, and this is dotted). How can I do this with devextreme charts? Is this possible?

I would be thankfull for some help.

Cheers.

Comment: Is this possible at all with devextreme? I'm trying it since hours and a didn't found a solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment the chart doesn't have the capability to display one series with the mix-line style.

There is, however, a way to create two series for one line. The first series can be used to show the solid-style part of the line and the second series for the dot-style part. Here is an example of such an approach:

```
$("#container").dxChart({
    dataSource: [{
        arg: 1,
        val1: 10
    }, {
        arg: 2,
        val1: 15
    }, {
        arg: 3,
        val1: 8
    }, {
        arg: 4,
        val1: 6
    }, {
       arg: 5,
       val1: 12
    }, {
       arg: 5,
       val2: 12
    }, {
       arg: 6,
       val2: 17
    }], 
    legend: { visible: false },
    series: [{
       color: "#334455",
        valueField: "val1",
        point: { visible: false }
    }, {
        color: "#334455",
        valueField: "val2",
        point: { visible: false },
        dashStyle: "dot",
        hoverStyle: {
            dashStyle: "dot"
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. Can you make a fiddle, so I can see the result? Cheers.

Comment: I've made one, this looks exactly like my searched solution, it's a good workaround for yet, I hope the developers of devextreme will implement soon the function to make multi-line-styles on the same line..Thanks and cheers.