# Customize tooltip in dxChart

Tags: javascript, charts, devexpress, tooltip, devextreme

I'm doing my first steps with dxchart of DevExtreme. At the moment I've got follow code:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>DevExtreme Chart</title>
        <!--FRAMEWOKR-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./lib/globalize.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./lib/dx.charts.js"></script>
        <!--JS-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="chart.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chartContainer" style="width:100%; height: 440px"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dataSource = [
        {
            argument: '15.06.2016',
            puls: 102,
            temperatur: 37.6,
            weight: 91
        },
        {
            argument: '16.06.2016',
            puls: 99,
            temperatur: 35.1,
            weight: 88
        },
        {
            argument: '17.06.2016',
            puls: 87,
            temperatur: 38.0,
            weight: 87
        },
        {
            argument: '18.06.2016',
            puls: 91,
            temperatur: 36.3,
            weight: 87
        },
        {
            argument: '19.06.2016',
            puls: 112,
            temperatur: 37.1,
            weight: 90
        }
    ];

    $("#chartContainer").dxChart({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        commonSeriesSettings: {
            type: "spline",
            label: {
                visible: false,
                connector: {
                    visible: false
                }
            },
            argumentField: "argument",
            axis: "pulsAxe"
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: true,
            customizeTooltip: function(obj) {
                return {
                    text: obj.seriesName
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            verticalAlignment: "top",
            horizontalAlignment: "right"
            },
        "export": {
            enabled: true
        },
        title: {
            text: "Hugo Amacher | 15.08.1977 (M)",
            subtitle: {
                enabled: true,
                text: "Ich bin ein Untertitel..."
            }
        },
        zoomingMode: "all",
        series: [
            {
                name: "Puls",
                valueField: "puls"
            },
            {
                name: "Temperatur",
                valueField: "temperatur",
                axis: "temperaturAxe"
            },
            {
                name: "Gewicht",
                valueField: "weight",
                axis: "weightAxe"
            }
        ],
        valueAxis: [
            {
                name: "pulsAxe",
                title: "Puls",
                position: "left",
                label: {
                    customizeText: function(value) {
                        return value.value + " bpm"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                name: "temperaturAxe",
                title: "Temperatur",
                position: "left",
                label: {
                    customizeText: function(value) {
                        return value.value + " °C"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                name: "weightAxe",
                title: "Gewicht",
                position: "left",
                label: {
                    customizeText: function(value) {
                        return value.value + " kg"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

My result is this:

[image]

As you can see, there is a simple spline chart, with three various y-axes and three various value-ranges for this axes on the chart. For each axe, I've got an label (bpm, °C and kg). I implemented also the tooltip of dxchart. At the moment when I hover a point, in the tooltip there is only the value. I also would like to add dynamicly to the tooltip the label after the value. That means, when I hover a value of the axe "Puls", it should show for example this: 91 bpm. How can I do this. I tried it with the customizeTooltip: http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Visualization_Widgets/dxChart/Configuration/tooltip/?version=16_1#customizeTooltip

I had the idea, to check the seriesName and assign the label in the return something like this, but it didn't work:

```
tooltip: {
    enabled: true,
    customizeTooltip: function(point) {
        if (point.seriesName == "Puls") {
            return {
                text: point.value + " bpm"
            }
        } else if (point.seriesName == "Gewicht") {
            return {
                text: point.value + " kg"
            }                    
        } else if (point.seriesName == "Temperatur") {
            return {
                text: point.value + " °C"
            }                         
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]Hi please check the Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/6Uoh30bb8qBNWIIbyX0O?p=preview

check your library includes

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/globalize/0.1.1/globalize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/15.2.5/js/dx.chartjs.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="width:100%; height: 440px"></div>
    <!-- Put your html here! -->
  </body>

</html>
```

and **JS**

```
// Add your javascript here
$(function(){
  var dataSource = [
        {
            argument: '15.06.2016',
            puls: 102,
            temperatur: 37.6,
            weight: 91
        },
        {
            argument: '16.06.2016',
            puls: 99,
            temperatur: 35.1,
            weight: 88
        },
        {
            argument: '17.06.2016',
            puls: 87,
            temperatur: 38.0,
            weight: 87
        },
        {
            argument: '18.06.2016',
            puls: 91,
            temperatur: 36.3,
            weight: 87
        },
        {
            argument: '19.06.2016',
            puls: 112,
            temperatur: 37.1,
            weight: 90
        }
    ];

    $("#chartContainer").dxChart({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        commonSeriesSettings: {
            type: "spline",
            label: {
                visible: false,
                connector: {
                    visible: false
                }
            },
            argumentField: "argument",
            axis: "pulsAxe"
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: true,
            customizeTooltip: function(obj) {
              console.log(obj.seriesName)
              if (obj.seriesName == "Puls") {
            return {
                text: obj.value + " bpm"
            }
        } else if (obj.seriesName == "Gewicht") {
            return {
                text: obj.value + " kg"
            }                    
        } else if (obj.seriesName == "Temperatur") {
            return {
                text: obj.value + " °C"
            }                         
        }

                // return {
                //     text: obj.seriesName
                // }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            verticalAlignment: "top",
            horizontalAlignment: "right"
            },
        "export": {
            enabled: true
        },
        title: {
            text: "Hugo Amacher | 15.08.1977 (M)",
            subtitle: {
                enabled: true,
                text: "Ich bin ein Untertitel..."
            }
        },
        zoomingMode: "all",
        series: [
            {
                name: "Puls",
                valueField: "puls"
            },
            {
                name: "Temperatur",
                valueField: "temperatur",
                axis: "temperaturAxe"
            },
            {
                name: "Gewicht",
                valueField: "weight",
                axis: "weightAxe"
            }
        ],
        valueAxis: [
            {
                name: "pulsAxe",
                title: "Puls",
                position: "left",
                label: {
                    customizeText: function(value) {
                        return value.value + " bpm"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                name: "temperaturAxe",
                title: "Temperatur",
                position: "left",
                label: {
                    customizeText: function(value) {
                        return value.value + " °C"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                name: "weightAxe",
                title: "Gewicht",
                position: "left",
                label: {
                    customizeText: function(value) {
                        return value.value + " kg"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer, but this doesn't work?!

Comment: check the screen shot which i attached

Comment: Hi with your script includes my screen is white and a get follow error in the console: GET https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/15.2.5/js/dx.chartjs.js net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Cheers

Comment: which doesnt means its not working. your question the answer is already solved if its not working becz of your other library conflicts it doesnt mean its not working ok

Comment: Hi - I had to remove the https:// and change it with http:// now it works, thanks!! Cheers and please edit this in your code.

Comment: i created in plunker the plunker will allow https so its not a problem

Comment: even u can use https if u enable the trusted site .. Happy coding @MrBuggy

Comment: thats true, but in some companies this is not allowed haha :D cheers

Comment: By the way, can you take a look on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990461/mixed-line-style-of-same-line-in-devextreme-chart 

Cheers